# unable to locate text boxes inside Modal Dialog Window?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where user `click` on `Add Address button` and `Address Detail Modal dialog window` is appeared,

It have 4 elements two text boxes for address detail info and two button  Add and Cancel.

I am able to click on  cancel and Add button in Model Dialog Window directly, but unable to locate text boxes inside it.

Below  is  code for text box in Modal Dialog Window.

```
input id="Address" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Address" data-toggle
="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="value:Address, ValidationMessage: Address" 
data-original-title="" title=""
```

**How to access modal box element** as Model Dialog window is part of `same window`
so `Alert` and `Window switching methods` might be not useful in that case ?
Please any advice?

**Update** Sample code that i am trying.

```
// Click on Address link It open Model window
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='member_78121']div/table/tfoot/tr/td/div/button")).click();
here i am giving wait condition.
//Inside modal window
//TextBox first
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressLine1")).sendKeys("plot no-23");
//textbox second
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressLine2")).sendKeys("plot no-23");
 //Add button 
driver.findElement(By.id("Add")).click();
// driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel")).click();
here i am able to click on Add or Cancel button if you comments text boxes code but 
i am getting error for textboxes "element is not visible"
```

This is Add button code for reference

```
button id="Add" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" type="button" title="" name="Add" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="click:$parent.SaveAndCloseAddressPopup,   Tooltip:$parent.SaveAndCloseAddressPopup"   
data-original-title="Save changes and close"
```

Comment: Error:"element is not visible" I tried wait also

Comment: There is no iframe even  other window.

Answer (score 0):

// Click on Address link It open Model window

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='member_78121']div/table/tfoot/tr/td/div/button")).click();

here i am giving wait condition.

//Inside modal window

```
//TextBox first
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressLine1")).sendKeys("plot no-23");
//textbox second
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressLine2")).sendKeys("plot no-23");
 //Add button 
driver.findElement(By.id("Add")).click();
```

// driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel")).click();

here i am able to click on Add or Cancel button if you comments text boxes code
but i am getting error for textboxes "element is not visible"

this is Add button code for reference

button id="Add" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" type="button" title="" name="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="click:$parent.SaveAndCloseAddressPopup, Tooltip:$parent.SaveAndCloseAddressPopup" data-original-title="Save changes and close"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressLine1")).sendKeys("plot no-23"); 
this try this 
driver.findElement(By.id("Address")).sendKeys("plot no-23");
```

as your sample code snippet for input box is

```
input id="Address" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Address" data-toggle
="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="value:Address, ValidationMessage: Address" 
data-original-title="" title=""
```

here you can clearly see id of the input tag is Address not AddressLine1

Comment: It was my mistake during editing its id is "AddressLine1"

Comment: ok please post exact html source code otherwise its become very difficult for anybody to give you right answer

Comment: This is html code for text box 1                                                                                                             <input id="AddressLine1" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="AddressLine1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-bind="value:AddressLine1, ValidationMessage: AddressLine1" data-original-title="" title=""/>

Comment: I think we can't handle element inside Modal dialog Window using webdriver  " http://automationplace.blogspot.in/2015/04/handling-modal-dialog-window-in.html "

Comment: if possible provide me the actual url so that i can give you a working example and also i do not believe as per your previous comment

Comment: Sorry @raj Its official application, Thanks for trying to help me